# Neural Network Doesn't Learn Multiplication (Toy Example)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

## **Toy Dataset**

- *Inputs*: Two integer numbers: `a` and `b`
- *Output*: Single integer number, which should be the product of `a` and `b`
- 8000 training examples

#### Sample of my `X_train`:

```
    array([[ 6220, 15403],
           [ 3197,  8054],
           [ 1723,  3711],
           ...,
           [ 9500, 14979],
           [ 2642, 16547],
           [15169, 19332]], dtype=int64)
```

#### Sample of my `Y_train`:

```
    array([ 95806660,  25748638,   6394053, ..., 142300500,  43717174,
            293247108], dtype=int64)
```

## **Model**

```
    def get_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(2,), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
        model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
        model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
        model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
        return model

    estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=get_model, epochs=20, batch_size=20,  verbose=1)
    estimator.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train))
```

## **Problem**

It seems to converge after just some epochs, with enormous training loss:

```
Epoch 1/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 378us/step - loss: 8970757661335224.0000
Epoch 2/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 1s 187us/step - loss: 1368236980395048.7500
Epoch 3/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 189us/step - loss: 731455474934743.0000
Epoch 4/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 200us/step - loss: 731256021644738.6250
Epoch 5/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 209us/step - loss: 729734634673274.8750
Epoch 6/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 215us/step - loss: 730761901553746.0000
Epoch 7/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 224us/step - loss: 729841294691532.7500
Epoch 8/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 235us/step - loss: 728911536487137.2500
Epoch 9/20
8000/8000 [==============================] - 2s 229us/step - loss: 731467433524592.6250
Epoch 10/20
```

## **What I tried to far?**

- Different Learning Rates, Learning Rate Decay
- More or less hidden layers / hidden units
- Different activation functions (→ ReLU, Leaky ReLU)
- Double checked my input and labels (→ Seems to be correct)

All of these actions don't improve the loss. Using less layers makes the result even worse.

## Edit

**If someone wants to play around with it – I've created a (IPython / Google Colab) notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19k-P-BiUlIdBYlbsuN1fjYGVaZAI1IlG).**

What I tried as well now:

- Initialization with `glorot_normal` → No significance change
- Normalizing with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` via `sc.fit_transform(dataset)` and inference with `sc.inverse_transform(result)` → Improved from ~ 7.3e14 to ~ 2.0e11
- Varying batch size → No significance change
- More data → 16.000 examples → Improved a little bit from ~ 2.0e11 to ~ 1.0e11
- Normalization via `math.log` (which makes `c = a * b` to `log(c) = log(a) + log(b)`, inference with `exp(predicted)` → Seems better → `1.02e9`, but it's still far from accurate – on a simple task like multiplication

Comment: See if this help https://keramatfar-a-s.medium.com/multiply-these-two-numbers-if-you-are-really-smart-fa118960e301.

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing your data (input *and* output) to have zero mean and unit variance.

In a second step, change your initializers to something like `glorot_normal`.

Comment: So, I've used ``glorot_normal`` and ``sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`` to normalize the values with ``sc.fit_transform(dataset)`` and trained some models with that. For inference I've used ``sc.inverse_transform(result)``. The results seem to be improved by some magnitudes, the mean squared error is down from ~ 7.3e14 to ~ 2.0e11. But still it's far from being an approximate multiplication.

Comment: you could try to increase the batch size as well, 20 may be too small.

Comment: I got it down to 1.05e11. I also created a MCV example and shared it via a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You are using very large values. Look at the mean relative absolute error (`mean(abs((output - target) / target))`) to get a better estimation of the model's performance during evaluation, that is independent of the input scale.

Furthermore consider using smaller values, e.g. in range `[0; 10]` restricting outputs to range `[0; 100]`, to avoid exploding gradients. You could divide the input by some `scale` (`>> 1`) accordingly and multiply the output by `scale^2`.

If you do NOT use the trick with `ln` and `exp` to transform multiplication into addition, you need much more layers and also should consider residual connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the **modeling**:

1. The network is too deep. For this simple problem, 1 hidden layer with 4 sigmoid neurons is enough. Too deep network only makes it difficult to converge.
2. The range of input/output is too large. The absolute value of input/output will affect the value of gradient and learning rate. If you use large input, you will need to use very large learning rate at the beginning, then gradually reduce it. Moreover, if `a` and `b` have different ranges, their parameters need different learning rates. To avoid all this problem, you should scale your data down, e.g., to 0 mean, 1 variance. But this scaling may affect the multiplication accuracy. More suitable for this problem is log scaling. *Note that*, in case you use log scaling, the problem is even more simple, it's just adding two numbers. You can use only 1 output layer with 1 linear neuron, no hidden layer needed.

However, the main problem is with **framework/hardware**.
Even with the exact weights ([[1., 1.], [0.]]), model output is still not exact, MSE on test set is still about 10^4. This, I assume, is because the low precision floating point number calculation in TF and/or on Colab, so it cannot calculate large number correctly.